# How to query LDAP (ADFS) by ObjectSID in PHP (or any language really)?

Tags: php, search, ldap, adfs

How can I query an object using LDAP with ObjectSID with PHP or any language for that matter?  I have found a ton of "solutions" that don't really makie sense and none really explain the source of the ObjectSID used except that it's binary.

For example, I've done an initial search and have retrieved the ObjectSID for future use.  The problem is the returned ObjectSID seems to be in binary.  How do I send that binary back to LDAP using PHP's ldap_search?

I've read that I should convert the value to Hex so I've done a `bin2hex($ObjectSID)`, but the value that I see via an LDAP browser: `S-1-5-21-1851920287-2048563450-226493979-1120` doesn't match my resulting value: `0105000000000005150000009f0f626efa981a7a1b06800d60040000`

Anyone have a clear answer?

Comment: Why is this question tagged with adfs? Ad would be more appropriate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, found the following answer:

```
// Returns the textual SID
public function bin_to_str_sid($binsid) 
{
    $hex_sid = bin2hex($binsid);
    $rev = hexdec(substr($hex_sid, 0, 2));
    $subcount = hexdec(substr($hex_sid, 2, 2));
    $auth = hexdec(substr($hex_sid, 4, 12));
    $result    = "$rev-$auth";

    for ($x=0;$x < $subcount; $x++) {
        $subauth[$x] = 
            hexdec($this->little_endian(substr($hex_sid, 16 + ($x * 8), 8)));
        $result .= "-" . $subauth[$x];
    }

    // Cheat by tacking on the S-
    return 'S-' . $result;
}

// Converts a little-endian hex-number to one, that 'hexdec' can convert
public function little_endian($hex) 
{
    $result = "";

    for ($x = strlen($hex) - 2; $x >= 0; $x = $x - 2) 
    {
        $result .= substr($hex, $x, 2);
    }
    return $result;
}


// This function will convert a binary value guid into a valid string.
public function bin_to_str_guid($object_guid) 
{
    $hex_guid = bin2hex($object_guid);
    $hex_guid_to_guid_str = '';
    for($k = 1; $k <= 4; ++$k) {
        $hex_guid_to_guid_str .= substr($hex_guid, 8 - 2 * $k, 2);
    }
    $hex_guid_to_guid_str .= '-';
    for($k = 1; $k <= 2; ++$k) {
        $hex_guid_to_guid_str .= substr($hex_guid, 12 - 2 * $k, 2);
    }
    $hex_guid_to_guid_str .= '-';
    for($k = 1; $k <= 2; ++$k) {
        $hex_guid_to_guid_str .= substr($hex_guid, 16 - 2 * $k, 2);
    }
    $hex_guid_to_guid_str .= '-' . substr($hex_guid, 16, 4);
    $hex_guid_to_guid_str .= '-' . substr($hex_guid, 20);

    return strtoupper($hex_guid_to_guid_str);
}
```